# Harshad Number issue

Tags: java

I have written a code below but every time I enter a non **Harshad** number still it is showing ,it is **Harshad** number

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    int c = 0;

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a number : ");

    a = in.nextInt();
    while (a > 0) {

        b = a % 10;
        c = c + b;
        a = a / 10;

    }
    if (a % c == 0) {
        System.out.println("number is harshad");

    } else {
        System.out.println("number is not harshad");
    }

}
```

Please notify my error.

Thanks
Saud

Comment: a = a / 10 return 0 for a values smaller than 10

Comment: Rather than asking us to find your bugs for you, you should learn to use a debugger.  Or failing that, learn how to use traceprints.  These are practical skills that every programmer should learn.  Now is a good time!  (Hint: the real point of homework exercises is to learn to program, and that includes debugging.)

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ Yes, but that doesn't matter for this purpose, in fact, it's exactly what you'd want. The idea is that `c` becomes the sum of the digits of the original number that was entered.

Comment: See [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the loop `a` is always `0` (because you are modifying the variable `a` in the loop) so that `a % c` is always `0` and the expression in the `if` statement always evaluates to `true`.

You have to store the original number that was entered somewhere, and in the `if` statement after the loop use that instead of the variable `a`.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    int c = 0;

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a number : ");

    int input = in.nextInt();

    a = input;
    while (a > 0) {

        b = a % 10;
        c = c + b;
        a = a / 10;

    }
    if (input % c == 0) {
        System.out.println("number is harshad");

    } else {
        System.out.println("number is not harshad");
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks @Jesper my issue is solved. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your code by :

```
a = in.nextInt();
int temp = a;
while (a > 0) {
    b = a % 10;
    c = c + b;
    a = a / 10;
}
if (temp % c == 0) { System.out.println("number is harshad"); } 
else { System.out.println("number is not harshad");}
```

You need to store the value of your input because it's that one you want to check in you `if` condition so because you modify `a` in the `while` you should store it elsewhere

Answer (score -1):

You iterate until a=0

You then ask if 0%x=0 which is always the case as a is 0.